# How can one find out if xfce session is locked?

Tags: session, cron, locking, xfce

i have to limit *working* xfce-session by 30 minutes, then lock it and prevent from unlocking for next 60 minutes.

1. I can find that one's xfce-session is active by `ps -aux | grep xfce-session`
2. I can lock the screen with `xflock4`

But how can i find out in cron script that the user's screen *is* locked?

Answer (score 3):

[xflock4](https://git.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-session/tree/scripts/xflock4) is just a script that normally runs xscreensaver or gnome-screensaver.

For xscreensaver you can query it with `xscreensaver-command -time` to check if it's locked or not and for how long. The gnome-screensaver counterpart is `gnome-screensaver-command -q`.